# iOS / mobile safari still zooms while viewport is set to user-scalable=no ? Check Accessibility settings!

Tags: ios, ios4, accessibility, viewport, meta-tags

*This specific Mobile Safari (seemingly impossible and yet undocumented) problem kept me going for a long long time today, and I was just about to post a question about it here when I figured it out.*

The problem: While I had set `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;"/>` my iPad web-app still allowed manual zooming (pinching in the browser). -- But only on my iPad, not on my iPhone.

Also I would rotate the device between portrait to landscape modes to check the the specific orientation-mode CSS codes, which gave strange results:

- Rotating from Landscape to Portrait there was no problem, the sizes and placement of everything kind of made sense.
- After that, rotating from Portrait back to Landscape and.. the viewport stayed as wide as it was in Portrait mode, ie. it was zoomed (scaled) in. I had to manually zoom out to get back to the full picture / viewport. Which should be impossible.

Comment: There are two settings preventing user from zooming but what are the benefits? I only see downsides.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I then found the great [iPad CSS Layout with Landscape/Portrait Modes](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/demos/ipad-css-layout/index.html) demo. It looked promising, but gave me the identical problem. Yet while testing this on a second iPad it worked perfect: no zooming problem whatsoever. So, we figured it had to do with my specific iPad.

Then it struck me: Weeks ago I fiddled around with the accessibility settings. Zooming in on the entire interface like you can do in OSX (ctrl+scroll) etc. Maybe this was linked to Mobile Safari in some way? Well, it turns out it is.

Today I learned: **When Accessibility > Zoom is turned on, this overrules the meta viewport settings.**

Try this out yourself? You'll find it here: `Settings > General > Accessibility > Zoom`

Comment: This is awesome! Finally a way to deal with those nasty websites forcing me to read their tiny text.

Answer (score 9):

As someone with vision problems I'm heavily reliant on being able to zoom mobile sites.  Now with the update to iOS 5 there's no way of getting iOS to ignore the user-scalable setting anymore and I suddenly discover I can't use half the web sites I use regularly anymore because I can't zoom them.

So, on behalf of people with vision problems, I beg you to please not use viewport meta tags to restrict peoples' ability to zoom your site!

Comment: I am also visually impaired, and find this annoying (particularly on Google searches), but you can still use the regular iOS zoom (double, three-finger tap), it's not as easy as just being able to pinch but does the job without irritating developers and, in a lot of cases messing up the UX.

Comment: @Ben I'd argue that the UX is ruined for people with poor vision by not being able to zoom.  Panning around when using the iOS zoom mode is a lot more difficult than panning around a zoomed web page.  And as for Android, that doesn't even provide an OS level zoom, so you're stuck.  And as far as irritating developers go, it's their job to get the UX right for everyone, not just people with 20/20 vision.  In some places not catering for the visually impaired is actually illegal as it breaches antidiscrimination legislation.

Comment: I totally agree, but android had bigger problems then web browser when it comes to accessibility, I've wanted an android phone since they first came out but simply can't read text messages etc! companies like Google really should know better.  And saying it messes up UX is just an excuse, and shouldn't be the case, but a lot of mobile web apps are designed for the specific screen size, and it may often be better UX to inslute a feature to just scale text rather than messing up the framing (e.g. the GMail app used to really mess up when you could zoom, the CSS had no idea what was going on!)

Comment: Accessibility is important and stuff, but this "answer" should at most be a comment.

Answer (score 4):

Just a little update for you: this has been [fixed](http://openradar.appspot.com/9025220) by Apple. As of iOS 5 beta 1, the Zoom accessibility setting will no longer cause the `viewport` meta tag to be ignored.

Comment: And now I can no longer use any mobile page that locks zooming because of this "fix".  Please don't disable zooming on mobile sites!

Answer (score 0):

Note: use commas as separators, not semicolons. The clean way are commas as separators. See the documentation page http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html, they do use commas too. And at least Chrome shows errors in the console if you use semicolons. I know, that this does not affect iPad or safari, but if you can do it clean, why not? :)