# Viewport meta tag not working in iPhone and Android

Tags: android, iphone, html, meta-tags, viewport

I am using the following html code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
    <head>
     <title>test</title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    test
    </body>
  </html>
```

My intention is to prevent user from zooming in or out. The above code isn't working in iPhone and Android. Any solution ?

**EDIT:** It appears in iPhone settings, if `Zoom` is selected as `On` under `Settings>Accessibility>Zoom`, then this will override meta tag. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788269/ios-mobile-safari-still-zooms-while-viewport-is-set-to-user-scalable-no-chec)

Not sure why it is happening in android.

Comment: Chrome users can overide meta with Settings/Advanced/Accessibility/Force enable zoom: checked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use this tag to prevent zoom on all mobile platforms :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
```

---

With `,` and not `;`

Comment: I tried this. Even though the effect of `width=device-width` is seen, I am still able to zoom-in and out.

Comment: Are you sure about the use of `;` instead of `,`? http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag say to use `,`.

Comment: I have the same problem, viewport doesn't work, I used this and it first worked but then became not work. This is my website : thechill.org . What can I do ?

Comment: This is wrong. Chrome gives a warning: `Error parsing a meta element's content: ';' is not a valid key-value pair separator. Please use ',' instead.`

Comment: I have a blog. On homepage, you can't zoom in or "scroll" sideways. On every other page, you can. The code is the same (I copied and pasted viewport stuff). What can it be?

Comment: I was battling the problem of having an undesired right margin, which let the user zoom out despite having min/max scale locked to 1 and user-scale to 0. It was the addition of the target-densityDpi=device-dpi attr/value that fixed it for me. Note that the [only correct separator](http://www.petelepage.com/blog/2013/02/meta-viewport-syntax-comma-or-semi-colon/) is the comma.

Answer (score 5):

In my part, I've this "viewport" which work good on an Android (Nexus 5) and on iPhone.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=0.5, minimum-scale=0.5; " />
```

I hope this help you !

Comment: This is what did it for me. For some reason an `initial-scale` of 1 results in an undesired right margin but an `initial-scale` of 0.5 to 0.9 works fine. I used 0.9 because I wanted as close to 1 as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Put this script to avoid pinch zoom. in latest version of safari, if meta tag not working

```
   document.documentElement.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {
     if (event.touches.length > 1) {
       event.preventDefault();
     }
   }, false);
```

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` was the only thing that worked for me. I used it as follows `.on("gesturechange", function(event) { event.preventDefault() `

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; height=device-height" />
```

worked well on Samsung Galaxy S3

Comment: Switching portrait to landscape and vice versa make trouble with this solution

Answer (score 1):

It seems it doesn't work any longer in the normal iOS (11.3) Browser.

However it still affects the webpage, if added to the homescreen, and launched from there.

So if you touch the share menu, select "Add to Home Screen", and open it up from there it will stop you from zooming as expected:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>luckydonald/SelfhostedMouse</title>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="SelfhostedMouse" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no; width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

Some time you need to add -webkit-flex:1 to containers (if flexbox in use ofcourse). That is helped me with my viewport problem.